# Бинд на один сокет

Tags: c++, linux, windows, сокет, boost

Заметил некорректную работу сокетов библиотеки `Boost`. Средствами этой библиотеки можно забиндить `n` сокетов на один адрес. Но! Если, например, есть `3` приложения - одно слушает сокет, второе шлет данные на него с другого сокета, а третье шлет данные на сокет первого приложения с этого же сокета(само себе по-сути).
Тогда рассмотрим следующие комбинации:

1. Запускаем 2 экземпляра первого приложения и потом один экземпляр второго.
2. Запускаем экземпляр первого приложения и третьего приложения.

В ситуации `1` принимать данные будет только приложение запущенное первым.

В ситуации `2` все зависит от порядка запуска: если первым запущено слушающее приложение, то данные принимаются и отправляются нормально, а если запустить сначала отправляющее, а потом принимающее - данные только шлются.

Сейчас опишу примеры этих приложений.

**ПРИНИМАЮЩЕЕ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ:**

```
char mess[2000];
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint ep = boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("10.177.17.25"), 9007);
boost::asio::io_service io;
SOCK s("10.177.17.25", 9007, io);

void Receive(boost::system::error_code ec_, size_t size_);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    s.s.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(mess, 2000), ep, boost::bind(Receive, _1, _2));
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    io.run();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void Receive(boost::system::error_code ec_, size_t size_)
{
    cout << "\nReceived:\n" << mess << "\n";
    s.s.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(mess, 2000), ep, boost::bind(Receive, _1, _2));
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
}
```

**ОТПРАВЛЯЮЩЕЕ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ:**

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint ep = boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("10.177.17.25"),9007);
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    SOCK s("10.177.17.25", 9007, io);
    string mess = "ASDFGHSKDJHIUADYUAFD";
    while (true)
    {
        s.s.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(mess.c_str(), mess.length()), ep);
        cout << "\n\nMESSAGE SENT!\n";
        io.run();
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    io.run();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Тип `SOCK` использованный в примерах - обертка для `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket` имеющее только конструктор, приведенный ниже и свойство - сам `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket s;`. Открываю сокет следующим образом:

```
SOCK::SOCK(string ip_, int port_, boost::asio::io_service& io_) :s(io_)
{
    //boost::asio::ip::udp::socket s; - в свойствах класса
    using boost::asio::ip::udp;
    s.open(udp::v4());
    s.set_option(udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
    s.bind(boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(ip_), port_));
}
```

**Теперь вопрос:** почему это так странно работает и как сделать так, чтобы работало нормально: в ситуациях `1` и `2` все данные принимались\отправлялись независимо от порядка запуска.

**P.S.** Сейчас продолжаю пробовать различные варианты опций сокета и запуска приложений. Обнаружил вот что для ситуации `2.`:
Если открыть отправляющее приложение, затем несколько принимающих, после этого закрыть отправляющее и открыть его опять, то одно из принимающих начнет принимать. Если его закрыть, то начнет принимать слудующее в порядке открытия и тд.

Comment: Вывод - не используйте один и тот же сокет в разных приложениях. И да вообще, `reuse_address` без повода - зло.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не особенность сокетов в бусте. Это особенность сокетов вообще. Линукс (тут и далее я буду писать о нем, о винде нужно отдельно уточнять) позволяет нескольким приложениям слушать один и тот же сокет. В этом случае входящие соединеня будут разбрасываться round-robin'ом (то есть, по очереди). Благодаря этому делают многие интересные штуки. К примеру, веб сервер может запустить несколько копий себя и хотя каждый экземпляр работает только в одном потоке, по факту получается "многопоточность" и с load balancer'ом из ядра. Но это все относиться к слушающему сокету tcp.

Посмотрев в код, можно увидеть, что там udp сокеты. С ними обычно так - кто первый сокет забиндил, тот и получает данные на него. Собственно это и объясняет наблюдаемое поведение. Почему так сложно? А дело в том, что в udp нет понятия серверный сокет (слушающий) или клентский. Там просто сокет, который может отправлять и получать данные. Поэтому видимо система так и делает.

Но если сокету указать, что он широковещательный/мультикаст, тогда все может заработать, но опять же очень интересно. В первом описанном случае два слушающих сокета будут получать данные от клиента. Во втором случае, также, но только скорее всего будет ещё "эхо" - будем получать свой же пакет.

Comment: Смотря как. Второй вариант как бы не исправить так, как Вам хочется. Первый - можно (но опять же, я не уверен).

Comment: Если Вы хотите использовать мультикаст группу, то нужно и айпи правильный брать. Просто так на любой апйи нельзя.

Comment: Если в кратце, то нужно, чтобы в разных программах данные приходили на этот сокет и могли с него отправляться. Для одного адреса есть только 1 принимающий и 1 отправляющий

Comment: Возможно, Вам нужно приложение-прокси.

Comment: Да, придется так, если не решу, как решить эту проблему